# Never pushing merged changes in git

Tags: git, merge, push

Let's say I have two branches in git: A and B. Say that I make a change in A and merge it into B. Then I push the latest version of B up to the remote but I never  push the changes from A up to the remote. In fact let's say that I completely revert that commit so it doesn't even exist anymore in A.

Are there any consequences to doing that for either branch? Will the remote copy of B be okay if A never gets pushed the changes that were merged into B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be Ok because branch B incorporates all commits from `HEAD` to the initial commit by successively following the parent or parents (in case of a merge) of a commit. A push will have to copy all commits that are not yet on the remote, otherwise the remote would have an incomplete history.

Consider the names A and B as labels that point to a specific commit.

What you describe is actually fairly common if you have a development model with feature branches: Usually feature branches branch off somewhere, get commits, get merged back and then deleted.

```
        B (master)                        B (master)
        |                                 |
x---x---M            becomes      x---x---M
 \     /              ---->        \     /
  x---x                             x---x
      |
      A (feature)
```

The commits from A are reachable from the merge commit M and the branch pointer B points to M. So no commits would be removed. Your situation is like pushing B but not A so the remote only ever sees the right version in the ASCII image above.

<sub>Side note: You could even delete both branches and the commits would still be there until the next garbage collection. This essentially eliminates the possibility of losing data that has been committed at some point in time.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be concerned if Branch B is somehow dependent on Branch A, since you merged a change in A into B.  **It is not**.

After merging A into B, you might have the following diagram, where `M` is the merge commit:

```
Branch A: X <- Y <- Z
Branch B: X <- M
```

Each commit in Git points to a top-level tree object, which in turns points to either more tree objects, or blobs containing data about the files included in that commit.

When you push your local Branch B, the repo will not know about any of the blobs referred to by this branch.  As a result, the Git repo will store the full tree for every commit in Branch B.

But let's say that you decided to do a `git rebase -i` on Branch B locally, and you modified the `X` commit by changing a single file.  Did you also modify Branch A when making this change?  **No, you did not**.  Before making this change, both Branches A and B referred to the same commit `X`.  But now Git created a new SHA-1 for the commit `X` which you modified in Branch B.  This new commit will point to a new tree object, which will ultimately point to a new blob containing the single file you modified.  Note that this tree may still share many other subtrees and blobs with Branch A.  But the commit and top-level tree will no longer be the same.

This is generally how Git branching works.  Information will be shared between branches as much as possible, and when branches diverge, then the underlying trees and blobs will be updated to reflect that.  So there is no concern about what happens to your Branch A after you have pushed Branch B to the remote.

Comment: Thanks Tim, can you explain your diagram a bit. I'm having trouble understanding what that is supposed to convey.

Comment: The diagram is supposed to give a visual to the scenario you outlined in your question.  Branch B is what you would be pushing to the remote.

Answer (score 0):

[image: I have created a repo commited locally on master]yes, will be okay.
The situation is that if I understand that:
suppose branch A is master and branch B develop

At first A and B are in the same state,and synchronized with origin
Locally I commit something to A, then I merged to B, and then only pushed to origin the branch B, and reset --hard A to HEAD.
That will be OK, that is one of the good things of git, you can do whatever you want locally, if you don´t push to origin.
And if some other develop push something to A, you should be able after reseting you branch A to head, to do git pull origin A without any conflict.

Example repo, take a look that I commited on master initially, and only in the repo exist develop.
https://github.com/ricardoul/StackoverflowMergedBranchAndNoCommit

Comment: Maybe because you took a screenshot of text?

Comment: I added the photo later :p, but I think that is clear with the view of the console, that writing the commands, in the console view you see the branches and the responses for the commands, and as you can see is a screenshot only with the console, not of all the screen.